# How can I escape a single quote?

Tags: html, escaping

How can I escape a `'` (single quote) in HTML?

This is where I'm trying to use it:

```
<input type='text' id='abc' value='hel'lo'>
```

The result for the above code is "hel" populated in the text box. I tried to replace `'` with `\'`, but this what I'm getting.

```
<input type='text' id='abc' value='hel\'lo'>
```

The result for the above code is "hel" populated in the text box.

How can I successfully escape the single quotes?

Comment: Hey Ravi, this is more of an html question. I retagged the question as HTML, but you might want to change that in your question.

Answer (score 417, accepted):

You could use HTML entities:

- `&#39;` for `'`
- `&#34;` for `"`
- ...

For more, you can take a look at *[Character entity references in HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML)*.

Comment: Why *should* one use double quotes for attribute values?

Comment: aahhhh!!.. Can't I even think of this. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: HUmph ; I'm guessing I *should* have said *could*, as it helps, in this specific case, but is not necessarily necessary ;; still, a *(in my opinion)* good reason would be that it's closer to XHTML.

Comment: It's the convention... see: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2

Comment: @Pascal MARTIN: XML does also allow single quotes for attribute values. (See http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-AttValue)

Comment: @Gumbo : wooo ! I don't think I've ever seen any XML document that was using single-quotes arround attributes values ; so I didn't think this was actually valid ;; I just *(once again)* learnt something while answering a question ; so, thanks for those comments !

Comment: I know this is old, but I think it's worth noting that there is an HTML entity for `"`: `&quot;`

Comment: @Pascal, w3c validator shows single quotes are valid for attributes. And see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210430/are-single-quotes-valid-in-html-xhtml

Comment: Thank you for hint , it was crashing on french accent so into javascript i repalce with utf8 character and add meta into html page to support utf 8 characters...
stringToRepalce.replace(/'/g, "&#39;");

Comment: @Gumbo I encountered a situation in ASP.Net with a user control... `<custom:Control Prop='<%# InsertSingleQuote ? "'" : "" %>' runat="server" />` failed to build. Converting the single quote to an HTML entity worked.

Comment: @Gumbo For example when you embed JSON in an attribute. `<a href="test.html" data-analytics="{&quot;event&quot;: &quot;click&quot;}">`. Or Javascript: `<a href="test.html" onclick="window.location.href = &quot;next.html&quot;">`. Many legit use-cases...

Answer (score 75):

You can use `&apos;` (which is iffy in IE) or `&#39;` (which should work everywhere). For a comprehensive list, see the [W3C HTML5 Named Character References](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/named-character-references.html) or the [HTML entities table on WebPlatform.org](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/html/entities#HTML_Entities_Table).

Comment: Wow, it's been awhile since I wrote this. Thanks for catching it - I've updated the links to two tables on W3C and WebPlatform.org.

Comment: These work "everywhere" except in VXML <var> Expression attributes where further escaping is necessary since in VXML <var> a String variable value is indicated as single quotes within the normal double quotes of the attribute definitions:  <var name="myvar" expr="'hel\&apos;lo'" />

Answer (score 10):

As you’re in the context of HTML, you need to use HTML to represent that character. And for HTML you need to use a [numeric character reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.3.1) `&#39;` (`&#x27;` hexadecimal):

```
<input type='text' id='abc' value='hel&#39;lo'>
```

Comment: but I didn't understand what do you mean by `context of html` ?

Comment: @coding_idiot Have a look at the different [tokens a HTML parser may encounter during the parsing process](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#tokenization). Each state has a different set of parsing rules that are triggered based on the input. Not every state allows character references. Now if you look at the [attribute value (single quoted)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attribute-value-\(single-quoted\)-state), you can see that a `&` denotes the begin of a character reference.

Answer (score 8):

Represent it as a text entity (ASCII 39):

```
<input type='text' id='abc' value='hel&#39;lo'>
```

Answer (score 6):

Probably the easiest way:

```
<input type='text' id='abc' value="hel'lo">
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you cannot escape the apostrophe character and you can't change it into a HTML entity (as it was in my case for a specific [Vue.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vue.js) property) you can use replace to change it into different apostrophe character from the UTF-8 characters set, for instance:

```
ʼ - U+02BC
’ - U+2019
```

Comment: This is a valid way of tackling the problem and I do it regularly. I just paste in the character directly.

Comment: I would avoid this if at all possible, and try to fix the underlying issue. It can cause unexpected problems. For example, if the user meant to include a code sample, then having characters changed like this will cause confusion for the users that copy and paste the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

I personally find the named HTML entities easier to remember:

- `&apos;` for `'` (known as single quote or *apostrophe*, Unicode character [U+0027](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0027))
- `&quot;` for `"` (known as double quote or *quotation mark*, Unicode character [U+0022](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0022))

Demo:

```html
&apos;
<br>
&quot;
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try using: `&#145;`

Answer (score -2):

use javascript inbuild functions escape and unescape

for example

```
var escapedData = escape("hel'lo");   
output = "%27hel%27lo%27" which can be used in the attribute.

again to read the value from the attr

var unescapedData = unescape("%27hel%27lo%27")
output = "'hel'lo'"
```

This will be helpful if you have huge json stringify data to be used in the attribute

Comment: `escape` is not unicode safe. The specification advises against its use.

Comment: [`escape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape) is deprecated. Also, it's not the type of escaping that is needed here, we are trying to escape `'` to an HTML entity like `&apos;` or `&#39;`, we are not trying to do percent-encoding, which has a different use-case.