# jQuery.html() with single quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't figure out how to write this so it works. We have a page where users can upload documents and the list will show on the screen. The problem comes when the filename has a single quote in it. We are using jQuery. There's some code generation going on but this is the basics of what comes out.

```
$(someElement).html('<label onclick="$(someOtherElement).attr(\'title\', \'TheFile\\'Name.pdf\')">Some Text</label>');
```

The single quote in the file name is causing a problem. I've tried escaping it both with one backslash and 2 backslashes. With a single backslash the code runs but produces this html:

```
<label onclick="$(someOtherElement).attr('title', 'TheFile'Name.pdf')">Some Text</label>
```

which now fails on the onclick.

With 2 backslashes, the jquery `html()` line won't run at all. In both cases I get Unexpected identifier, just at different points.

Comment: You may want to correct what appears to be a typo in your code `#(someElement)`. I reformatted your question but didn't change the content.

Comment: Use better jQuery functionality. For example, create a label like `$("<label>")`, and set its inner text with `.text("Some Text")`. You can add event handlers with `.on("click", function () { /* FUNCTION CODE */ })`. If you want to clear everything in `$(someElement)`, use `$(someElement).empty()`, and then add the label with `.append(Your_Label_Variable);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a tripple backslash :

```
$(someElement).html('<label onclick="$(someOtherElement).attr(\'title\', \'TheFile\\\'Name.pdf\')">Some Text</label>');
```

Why 3?

The first one escape the second backslash that will escape the `'` **in the HTML code**.

The third one escape the `'` to prevent the string from closing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to not just double but triple the backslashes.

The reason is that you initially escape the `'` by doing `\'`. Now however you have two characters to escape so `\` goes to `\\` and `'` goes to `\'` again giving `\\\'`.

Answer (score 0):

[How to escape single quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428572/how-to-escape-single-quote)

Try using the character values with the & symbol to escape quotes.

Comment: Thanks. I tried using the character value but it behaved just as if I had tried escaping it with a single back slash. I still got the same html and the onclick fails.