# AngularJS - HTML in JS - Escaping single quote

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to do this in javascript, I can't do it in the html (at least not without breaking everything, I hope to put it out into the html later on).

If it was in plain html, the div would look like this (**'my-border'**):

```
<div class="col-xs-12" ng-class="{'my-border': hasBorder">...</div>
```

But since it's in javascript, the whole html line needs to be surrounded in single quotes
(**'my-border'**):

```
template: '<div class="col-xs-12" ng-class="{'my-border': hasBorder">...</div>'
```

I've tried the following (from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428572/how-to-escape-single-quote)):

**"my-border"**

```
template: '<div class="col-xs-12" ng-class="{"my-border": hasBorder">...</div>'
```

**\'my-border\'**

```
template: '<div class="col-xs-12" ng-class="{\'my-border\': hasBorder">...</div>'
```

**'my-border'**

```
template: '<div class="col-xs-12" ng-class="{&#39;my-border&#39;: hasBorder">...</div>'
```

But I get **Syntax Error: Unexpected String**

I am new to this group, so I first searched the archives and didn't find anything. 
If anyone could help me out or link me to an existing topic, I would really appreciate it!

Thank you so much for your time!!

Shannon :]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only problem that I see in your code is the un-terminated curly brace in your ng-class directive, it lacks the `}` symbol. After adding that, escaping the single quotes should solve your problem.

```
template: '<div class="col-xs-12" ng-class="{\'my-border\': hasBorder}">...</div>'
```

See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DU3phOdoCTrX4EQ96P0Z?p=preview) as an example.

Comment: oh my gosh I don't know how i missed that, great catch thank you! However, i still get an **Error: Invalid template**

Comment: can you post a plunker with your code, it may help us track these problems.

Comment: I would like to - I'm just not sure how to. I'm very new to web-development and I'm trying to create a grid using KendoUI. The KendoUI has set fields for each column such as field, title, width, and template. Template is the HTML that will be put into a column. In my grid, I would like to have a colored border around any cells when the hasBorder field in their json response is set to true. Anyways, here's a plunker with the basic idea, i hope this helps -- http://plnkr.co/edit/dA3od4ZGRxarOrnwVFWl?p=preview

Comment: It's solved, thank you so much for your help ryeballar, the \' works perfectly for the my-border, I had a seperate syntax error: 

'<div class="col-xs-12" ng-class="{'my-border': #: hasBorder #}"><span class="gridItem">#: previousValue </span></div>'

I was missing the # (kendoUI syntax), it should look like this: 

'<div class="col-xs-12" ng-class="{'my-border': #: hasBorder #}"><span class="gridItem">#: previousValue #</span></div>'

Comment: Like i said, i'm very new to web development, at heart i'm a java programmer. Javascript syntax is still very wobbly for me, web development is a whole new world! haha I really appreciate all of your help!! Thank you again!!!

Comment: Just a thought - any ideas on how to separate this html out of the javascript so that it exists in a separate html file?

Comment: yes you can use the templateUrl option instead.. e.g. templateUrl: 'templates/my_row.html'

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, but I was trying to escape single quotes in html. I ended up solving it by using a double backslash:

`<div my-directive="'Here\\'s a message with a single quote.'"></div>`

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to quote the class:

```
<div class="col-xs-12" ng-class="{my-border: hasBorder}">...</div>
```

This will add class `my-border` to the div when `hasBorder` evaluates to true.

Comment: I got an Error: Invalid template on this one

Comment: Just out of curiosity, i went into my HTML where i use the my-border class, it looks like this: 

<div class="col-xs-12 my-container" ng-class="{ 'my-border': myCount > 0}">

I removed the ''s around 'my-border' from the html and ran it and got a bunch of errors, all of them matched the following: 

Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '-' is unexpected, expecting [:]

Comment: It's true that you in general don't have to put quotes around the classNames, however when you use a dash in the className you do have you put it in quotes

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a

```
template: "<div class=\"col-xs-12\" ng-class=\"{'my-border': hasBorder\">...</div>"
```

work?

Comment: it wasn't the double quotes i'm trying to escape, it's the single quotes around 'my-border' that's giving me the problem. I tried using the escape \ character on these like so: 

template: '<div class="col-xs-12" ng-class="{\'my-border\': hasBorder">...</div>'

But no luck. Thank you for your reply though!

Comment: Jep, I just thought turning it around would be the solution... :)

Comment: Sorry, no it did not solve my problem. ryeballar's solution did solve my problem. Thank you for contributing though!