# Add Blackslah JSP in Javascript code

Tags: javascript, jsp

i want  to add backslash after apostrof character (')

**before**  thi's  is string

**after**   thi\'s is string (I want like this)

okey, this is my code,

```
       function showdata(mydata)
    {
        alert (mydata)
    }

//if this click, show alert showdata
<%
    String mydata= "Hello Worl'd";
%>
<a onclick="showdata('<% out.print(mydata.replace("'","\\\'")); %>'); return false;">Click Data</a>
```

i already click, this alert not show

Help me, Thank's

Comment: do you get any errors in console?  I just noticed that you have declared the function `showdata(..)` but the `onclick` event is invoking `edit_tipe(...)` - could that be it?

Comment: sorry, i already update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to pass hello wor'ld as arument as it contains ' character .do this way

```
 <script>
         function showdata(mydata)
    {

        alert (mydata);
    }</script>
if this click, show alert showdata
<%
    String mydata= "Hello World";
    mydata=mydata.replace("\'", "\\\'");

%>
<a onclick="showdata('<%=mydata%>');">Click Data</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

A single quote is just the character that you see in this place. Instead of using `String.replace` for a single character, you should do proper escaping of all of the data that you're using on the JSP. Check this [OWASP cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet), particularly Rule#3 (but don't stop there).

Find a proper library that works for you and use that library's escape method(s).

But the direct answer to your question [is this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428572/how-to-escape-single-quote): Don't escape by using `\'`, rather go for `&#39;`. Do yourself a favor and don't stop there.