# PHP- correct use of quotation marks inside each other

Tags: php, quotes, double-quotes

PHP - The correct way to use single && double quotation marks inside one another. For example:

```
<?php
   if($_SESSION['id']){  
      echo "<button class='logout' onclick='location.href='?logoff''>Logout</button>";
   }
?>
```

I am fairly new to programming but it is my understanding that single quotes go inside of the double quotes. Any help would be appreciated - Thank You.

Comment: HTML escaping in that context.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428572/how-to-escape-single-quote

Comment: O.k. Thank you very much