# How can I add json stringify in string javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, modal-dialog

My code like this :

```
<script>
var res = `
        <a href="#" id="edit-image"
           data-toggle="modal"
           data-target="#modal-edit-image"
           data-photo="`+JSON.stringify(photo)+`" 
        >
            <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>
        </a>`;                                                 
</script>
```

The result of `console.log(photo)` like this :

> Object {id: 5, name: "IMziQFBIxFEFQHdjlg3mGXEVuQnwqZ5rYigX2jlq.jpeg",
>   alt: "dea"}

I want to change it to json string and save it in variable res

I do it like above code, but if I inspect element and I copy the element the result like this :

```
<a href="#" id="edit-image" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-edit-image" data-photo="{" id":5,"name":"imziqfbixfefqhdjlg3mgxevuqnwqz5ryigx2jlq.jpeg","alt":"dea"}"="">
    <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>
</a>
```

It seems json stringfy in the element untidy

How can I solve it?

Comment: Is there a reason why you wanted to place a `json` data as a value for your `data-photo` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` uses `"` as default string delimiters. Just wrap the value of the `data-photo` attribute in `'` quotes instead of `"` quotes:

```
var res = `
    <a href="#" id="edit-image"
        data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#modal-edit-image"
        data-photo='${JSON.stringify(photo)}'
    //             ^ here                   ^ and here
    >
        <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>
    </a>`;
```

**Note 1:** One of the benefits of using [**Template Literals**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) is that you can use `${}` instead of the `+ ... +` syntax.

**Note 2:** If the properties of the object `photo` could have a `'` quote in them as in:

```
var photo = {id: 5, name: "I'm here.jpg", alt: ""};
//                         ^^^
```

then you'll have to escape it like [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2428572/6647153):

```
JSON.stringify(photo).replace(/'/g, "&#39;")
//                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ replace all single quotes with their escaped values
```

following this last method, you can keep double quotes as in the code in the question, but this time escaping double quotes instead:

```
var res = `
    <a href="#" id="edit-image"
        data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#modal-edit-image"
        data-photo="${JSON.stringify(photo).replace(/"/g, "&#34;")}"
    //             ^ here                                          ^ and here
    // use double quotes to surround the value of data-photo and excape " in the result of JSON.stringify
    >
        <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>
    </a>`;
```

Comment: @TrendingNews You're welcome! One question: Could the `name` and `alt` properties contain a `'`? That will cause an error. I'm still looking for a solution for that, I'll post as soon as I figure it out.

Comment: Yes, it looks like it could contain `'`. Okay. Thanks

Comment: @TrendingNews found it.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot

Comment: I need you help. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44486251/why-image-not-display-in-modal-bootstrap