# How to do a single quote inside of a double quote inside a single quote?

Tags: html

I have a simple piece of html code like this:

```
<button onclick = 'getAnsVoc("J'ai attendu mon ami.", "Q2A", "Q2B", "Q2C", "Q2D")'>Answer</button>
```

It is super simple but I have no idea how to make the expression valid while still being able to have the apostrophe in the code. I did not know how to phrase it so I came here for answers.

Comment: You need to "escape" it using a backslash ``\``

Comment: Thanks, but where would I put the backslash

Comment: right before the `'`, so like this `\'`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character

Comment: `<button onclick='getAnsVoc("J\'ai attendu mon ami.", "Q2A", "Q2B", "Q2C", "Q2D")'>Answer</button>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape a single quote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428572/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote)

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the character (`'`) that is the same character as the "wrapper" (`'`). You usually do this with a preceeding slash : `\'`.

Therefore:

```
<button onclick='getAnsVoc("J\'ai attendu mon ami.", "Q2A", 
                "Q2B", "Q2C", "Q2D")'>Answer</button>
```

As an alterative you can also replace the character with it's [HTML entity name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML). For `'` you can use `&#39;`. Therefore:

```
<button onclick='getAnsVoc("J&#39;ai attendu mon ami.", "Q2A", 
                "Q2B", "Q2C", "Q2D")'>Answer</button>
```

---

If you are playing with user submitted (or otherwise dynamic) data and you need to ensure that single (`'`) and double (`"`) quotes are correctly encoded to be "safe" in javascript then you need a function to *"encode"* these elements.

An example of this sort of functionality is at the bottom of the links list below:

---

## Useful links:

- [Escaping in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery)
- [Escaping in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004168/escape-quotes-in-javascript)
- [How do I escape a single quote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428572/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote)
- [HTML Character Entity Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML)
- [Encode html entities in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749591/encode-html-entities-in-javascript)