# Array content malformed when used on html

Tags: python, html, arrays, django, dictionary

I have the following loop:

```
for elem in Data.objects.filter(user=id):
                variables['labels'].append(time.strftime("%H%M%S", time.localtime(elem.timestamp)))
```

This produces the following result:

```
['000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '000000']
```

But when I inspect the html this is the result:

```
labels: [&#39;000000&#39;, &#39;000000&#39;, &#39;000000&#39;, &#39;000000&#39;, &#39;000000&#39;, &#39;000000&#39;, &#39;000000&#39;, &#39;000000&#39;, &#39;000000&#39;, &#39;000000&#39;, &#39;000000&#39;, &#39;000000&#39;, &#39;000000&#39;, &#39;000000&#39;, &#39;000000&#39;, &#39;000000&#39;, &#39;000000&#39;, &#39;000000&#39;]
```

Why this happens?

Comment: `&#39;` means a single quote in HTML. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2428572/10077 Does the HTML render the way you want it to?

Comment: I'm using the following to render the html: `return render(request, 'interface/data.html', {'user_id': id, 'data': variables})`. How I can fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it with the following filter:

```
{{ data.labels|safe }}
```