# Apostrophe in DocuSign for Salesforce URL button

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

We recently converted our DocuSign for Salesforce buttons from JavaScript to URL format and I'm having trouble now getting an apostrophe to show up in my subject line.

In the JavaScript button code, the format was:

```
CES='Document for '+ Account.Name + '\'s Approval '
```

However in URL format, this outputs as:

```
Document for Test Corp\'s Approval
```

How do I get the apostrophe to appear properly?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape a single quote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428572/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote)

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better solution than this but I figured out that if I use a Custom Label I could make this work.

I created a Custom Label called Apostrophe with a value of ' I could reference that in the code.

```
CES='Document for '+ Account.Name + $Label.Apostrophe + 's Approval '
```

That seems to do the trick.

[Custom Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iL8Tb.png)