# HTML entities incorrectly encoding in API call

Tags: java, api, character-encoding, html-entities, html-encode

I am about to use Paxful API method for sending a message to trade:

```
String message = "Do NOT PRESS 'Paid' button, until your transfer get 'Success' status.";
paxfulService.sendMessage(tradeId, message);
```

But here is what I see in the browser:

[image: Screenshot of pop up with incorrectly formatted punctuation]

This is my fault, or Paxful API use unnecessary HTML encoding?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428572/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote) question may be related

Answer (score 0):

The API you are using is re-encoding the single quotes back into their hex values.

In your original `message` string try using `&#39;` in the place of the single quotes you have.

Comment: not works, here is what i get: `Do NOT PRESS &amp;#39;Paid&amp;#39; button, until your transfer get &#039;Success&#039; status.`