# How to use escape characters in an alt attribute inside an img element in HTML?

Tags: html, image, text, alt, html-escape-characters

Is this the right way to use escape characters in `alt` attributes for alt text of an `img` element?

I have the below code:

```html
<h3>Option 1</h3>
<img src="image.jpg" 
     alt='Version of "Whistler\'s Mother" in cubist style'>

<br><br>

<h3>Option 2</h3>
<img src="image.jpg" 
     alt="Version of \"Whistler's Mother\" in cubist style">
```

Either of the two options above do not work properly as the alt text. The alt text that I wanted to display is:

`Version of "Whistler's Mother" in cubist style`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I escape a single quote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428572/how-can-i-escape-a-single-quote)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, use the [HTML entity](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Common_HTML_entities_used_for_typography) instead. E.g. `&apos;` or `&quot;`:

```html
<h3>Option 1</h3>
<img src="image.jpg" 
     alt='Version of "Whistler&apos;s Mother" in cubist style'>

<br><br>

<h3>Option 2</h3>
<img src="image.jpg" 
     alt="Version of &quot;Whistler's Mother&quot; in cubist style">
```