# Is there anyway I can escape ' without affecting the whole html in azure cognitive service translation?

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services, language-translation, azure-text-translation

LANGUAGE #1

```
'<div><span style="">Santé méritétaine,</span> Sam’s Club.</div>'
```

LANGUAGE #2

```
'<div><span style=\"\">Meritain Salud,</span> Sam's Club.</div>'
```

Using azure cognitive service, I've translated two htmls. Above are their results.

The first one got no error because the ’ doesn't cuts the string in the word Sam’s.

I got problem in the second one because ' used is the same with the string syntax. It becomes ''' .

Escaping ' character means replacing ' to '' characters. Also, it might not good to use replace extension because the whole html might be affected.

is there anyway I can escape ' without affecting the whole html?

Answer (score 0):

Some possible methods are:

Doubling the single quote characters, e.g., ’ becomes ‘’.

Using a backslash to escape the single quote, e.g., ’ becomes '.

Replacing the single [quote with an HTML entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428572/how-can-i-escape-a-single-quote).