# Does it matter which ' and " marks are used?

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to Use Double or Single Quotes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript)
>   [Are single quotes valid in HTML/XHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210430/are-single-quotes-valid-in-html-xhtml)

In the world of XHTML, HTML, Javascript etc. does it matter if you use `'` or `"` when writing code as long as you stick to one or the other?  And is it better to use one over the other and why?

Comment: IMO it's largely preference. I use `"` when writing plain JavaScript, and `'` when inside a tag event handler attribute (which is rare enough these days).

Comment: If this was asking about Javascript only it would be a duplicate but I am also asking about HTML and XHTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

being XML, XHTML will only take the double quote.  HTML being SGML can take either.  JavaScript, though, doesn't care as long as you are consistent withing a single string (that is opening and closing with the same character).

Comment: HTML does allow single quoted attributes.

Comment: Umm?  [3.2.2 Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2) "By default, SGML requires that all attribute values be delimited using either double quotation marks (ASCII decimal 34) or single quotation marks (ASCII decimal 39)."

Comment: my bad... it's being a while since I last looked at the SGML spec.  Fixing the answer...

Comment: With XHTML Transitional will it take single `'` when XHTML Strict will not?

Comment: XML (including XHTML) also allows single or double-quotes. The idea that XML only allows double-quotes is widely believed but not true. Have a look at [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-AttValue)

Comment: Either way, be it XHTML or HTML, it makes no sense to use single quotes.  Double quotes are the standard, and should always be used.  In JavaScript, I argue the same point, use double quotes always.  It is easy enough to escape quotes.