# php inside html div css style tag

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to insert a dynamic php value into a html style tag, I am not sure if i am doing the correct way?

```
<div class="status" style='background: <?php get_option("myoption_background_color") ?>'>
```

Comment: Do you get an error or why do you ask?

Comment: You are not sure? Does it work?

Comment: Your syntax is wrong first of all. Your style attribute uses different quotes.

Comment: i don't get any errors

Comment: Somebody actually upvoted this question? Really?

Comment: is that the best practice? or is there any other ways to call the php in this style tag?

Comment: Theres no best practice about it, if it's wrong it won't work. A starting `'` must be paired with an ending `'` and the same with `"`.

Comment: @F4r-20 [Single quotes are valid in html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210430/are-single-quotes-valid-in-html-xhtml)

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV At what point did I say that single quotes aren't valid in HTML?

Comment: @F4r-20 none, just pointing it out in case ... :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot the semicolon and echo, check [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option):

```
<div class="status" style="background: <?php echo get_option("myoption_background_color"); ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you also need `echo`:

```
<div class="status" style="background: <?php echo get_option("myoption_background_color"); ?>">
```

If a function is called `getSomething` then it likely returns the value, but not writes it to output.