# Show data from form into automated table

Tags: javascript, html

I have a basic table inside of a form, but the function addData doesn't seem to run when I click the <kbd>Add</kbd> button. How can I fix it?

I am trying to make an automatic table to keep track of the needed information.

```js
document.getElementById('DateField').valueAsDate = new Date();

function addData() {
  var store_price = document.getElementById("price");
  var store_moneyback = document.getElementById("moneyback");
  var store_profit = document.getElementById("profit");
  var store_date = document.getElementById("DateField");
  var store_gametype = document.getElementById("gametype");
  var table = document.getElementById("dymanictable");
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = store_price.value;
  row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = store_moneyback.value;
  row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = store_profit.value;
  row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = store_date;
  row.insertCell(4).innerHTML = store_gametype;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table id='dymanictable'>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="price">Price:</label><br></td>
      <td> <input type="text" id="price" name="price"><br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <label for="moneyback">Money back:</label><br></td>
      <td> <input type="text" id="moneyback" name="moneyback"><br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <label for="profit">Profit:</label><br></td>
      <td> <input type="number" id="profit" name="profit" min="-100" max="100"><br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <label for="DateField">Current date:</label>

      <input type="date" id="DateField" name="DateField" readonly>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <label for="gametype">Gametype:</label></td>
      <td>
        <select id="gametype" name="gametype">
          <option value="cashgame">Cash game</option>
          <option value="twister">Twister</option>
          <option value="blackjack">Blackjack</option>
          <option value="sitgo">Sit&Go</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <button onclick="addData()">Add</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It _does_ get called - but any effect it might have had, is immediately negated by the form getting submitted, which reloads the page. Add `type="button"` on your button element, to make this a "click button", instead of a _submit_ button.

Comment: Re *"dymanictable"*: Do you mean *"dynamictable"*? (*[dynamic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dynamic#Adjective)*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty much close. You have to create a new table after `</form>` with headings.

The solution is given below:

```js
document.getElementById('DateField').valueAsDate = new Date();

function addData() {
    var store_price = document.getElementById("price");
    var store_moneyback = document.getElementById("moneyback");
    var store_profit = document.getElementById("profit");
    var store_date = document.getElementById("DateField");
    var store_gametype = document.getElementById("gametype");

    var table = document.getElementById("dymanictable");

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = store_price.value;
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = store_moneyback.value;
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = store_profit.value;
    row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = store_date.value;
    row.insertCell(4).innerHTML = store_gametype.value;
}

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

```html
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="price">Price:</label><br></td>
            <td> <input type="text" id="price" name="price"><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <label for="moneyback">Money back:</label><br></td>
            <td> <input type="text" id="moneyback" name="moneyback"><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <label for="profit">Profit:</label><br></td>
            <td> <input type="number" id="profit" name="profit" min="-100" max="100"><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <label for="DateField">Current date:</label>

            <input type="date" id="DateField" name="DateField">

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <label for="gametype">Gametype:</label></td>
            <td> <select id="gametype" name="gametype">
                    <option value="cashgame">Cash game</option>
                    <option value="twister">Twister</option>
                    <option value="blackjack">Blackjack</option>
                    <option value="sitgo">Sit&Go</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <br>

    <button onclick="addData()">Add</button>
</form>

<table id="dymanictable" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>price</th>
        <th>moneyback</th>
        <th>profit</th>
        <th>DateField</th>
        <th>gametype</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: A side note, *"here single quote should be replaced with double quote..."* this is not required nor has anything to do with the OP's issue. Single quotes are [valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210430/are-single-quotes-valid-in-html-xhtml/2210452#2210452) in `HTML` attributes just like double quotes.

Comment: *Why* is it necessary to create a new table? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73813196/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today). From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*.

Answer (score 2):

When you click the <kbd>Add</kbd> button, you actually submit the form, because you didn't specify a `type` for that button which defaults to `type=submit`.

The fix is fairly easy. You either specify the `type=button` which doesn't submit the form or you can prevent the form submission in the JavaScript part.

Here's a fixed version of your code that use the JavaScript code fix which basically *cancels* the click event of the button. Thus the form doesn't get submitted and the rest of your `addData` function should be executed as wanted:

There are plenty of ways to fix that, and I am not going to showcase them all for the sake of simplicity and shortness.

```js
document.getElementById('DateField').valueAsDate = new Date();

/** that function now expects a parameter, the "event" object */
function addData(e) {
  /** prevent the form submission */
  e.preventDefault();
  var store_price = document.getElementById("price");
  var store_moneyback = document.getElementById("moneyback");
  var store_profit = document.getElementById("profit");
  var store_date = document.getElementById("DateField");
  var store_gametype = document.getElementById("gametype");
  var table = document.getElementById("dymanictable");
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = store_price.value;
  row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = store_moneyback.value;
  row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = store_profit.value;
  row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = store_date;
  row.insertCell(4).innerHTML = store_gametype;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table id='dymanictable'>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="price">Price:</label><br></td>
      <td> <input type="text" id="price" name="price"><br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <label for="moneyback">Money back:</label><br></td>
      <td> <input type="text" id="moneyback" name="moneyback"><br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <label for="profit">Profit:</label><br></td>
      <td> <input type="number" id="profit" name="profit" min="-100" max="100"><br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <label for="DateField">Current date:</label>

      <input type="date" id="DateField" name="DateField" readonly>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <label for="gametype">Gametype:</label></td>
      <td>
        <select id="gametype" name="gametype">
          <option value="cashgame">Cash game</option>
          <option value="twister">Twister</option>
          <option value="blackjack">Blackjack</option>
          <option value="sitgo">Sit&Go</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <!-- pass the "event" object to the click listener -->
  <button onclick="addData(event)">Add</button>
</form>
```

**Note:** the line `row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = store_date` (and the one next) are not typing the value from that input, but instead the input element itself which calls the `toString` method on it which prints `[object HTMLInputElement]`. The fix is fairly simple, but is out of the scope of the answer.